# Updating an object that is used inside another object

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, database-design

I have an app that allows you to create employees, but I have a problem when renaming employee positions.

I have an array of positions that looks something like this:

```
positions: [
  { id: 1, title: 'Masseuse' },
  ...
];
```

If I create an employee, I have to select a position from a dropdown, and the employees end up looking something like this:

```
employees: [
  { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', title: 'Masseuse' },
  ...
];
```

This approach works fine until the user renames a position. For example, if the user renames 'Masseuse' to 'Massage Therapist', the position dropdown will update as expected, but the employees' with that position will still say 'Masseuse'.

If a user renames a position, do I also need to find each employee with that position and update them individually? Or is there a different approach that I should be taking? I'm wondering if the employee object should store the position ID since that will never change and then somehow use that to display their position title, but I don't know how that would work.

I'm not experienced with backend development or database architecture yet, so this may not be important information, but I'm only using a fake REST API at the moment. I will eventually setup an actual database, but haven't gotten to that yet.

FWIW, I'm using Angular and the following mock API: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Yes, the `employee` object should store the position `id`. See [this article](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-foreign-key/) about primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the position id to store the title. And then display the title by the stored position id.

```
employees: [
 { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', titleId: 1 },
 ...
];
```

Then your dropdown would be like below

```
<select [(ngModel)]="editingEmployee.titleId"">
  <option *ngFor="let x of positions" [value]="x.id">{{x.title}}</option>
</select>
```

And now when you are displaying an employee, you could refer to the positions array from the stored `titleId` of the employee.

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees">
   {{employee.name}} is a {{getPosition(employee.titleId)}}
</div>
```

And in your component

```
getPosition(titleId) {
  const position = this.positions.filter(p => p.id === titleId);

  return position[0] ? position[0].title : '';
}
```

Refer to this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-mff293?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Are you sure about `positions[titleId]`?

Comment: Sorry it should be corrected, I have updated the answer thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Nice reasoning.

What you are thinking is the correct way to go about it.

This aligns with the concept of database normalization which is a structured way of reducing redundancy in your architecture.

Se also **database normalization** in wikipedia: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution will be to store a position id instead of title inside employee object.

And when you need to display it you can construct "view" of that object:

```
let positions = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Masseuse' },
  ...
];

let employees = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', positionId: 1 },
  ...
];

function getPositionTittle(id, positions) {
  const position = positions.find(p => p.id === id);

  if (!position) return '';

  return position.title;
}

function prepare(employee, positions) {
  const title = getPositionTittle(employee.positionId, positions);
  return {
    ...employee,
    title
  };
}

const employeeView = prepare(employees[0], positions);
// employeeView = { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', positionId: 1, title: 'Masseuse' }
```